# Execute string contained in a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to execute a query contained in a string column in SQL Server; how can I do that?

I need to update a column with the result of the query contained in `sql_text`:

[image]

The query that generates that is:

```
    id_coordenadaGPS, 
    CONCAT('UPDATE CoordenadaGPS SET ogr_geometry = geometry::', 
    ( CASE poly_type
        WHEN 'POLYGON' THEN 'STPolyFromText'
        WHEN 'LINESTRING' THEN 'STLineFromText'
        ELSE 'STPointFromText'
     END ),
     '("', poly_string, '", 4326) WHERE id = ', id_coordenadaGPS) as sql_text
FROM (
    SELECT CONCAT(poly_type, '(', point, ')') as poly_string, Id_CoordenadaGPS, poly_type FROM (
        SELECT 
            (CASE 
                WHEN y.TOTAL_POINTS = 1 THEN 'POINT' 
                WHEN y.TOTAL_POINTS >= 3 THEN
                    CASE WHEN y.first_point = y.last_point THEN 'POLYGON' ELSE 'LINESTRING' END
                ELSE 'LINE'
            END) as poly_type,
            point,
         Id_CoordenadaGPS
        FROM (
            SELECT STRING_agg( CAST(CONCAT(Latitud,' ', Longitud) as nvarchar(max)), ',') as point, Id_CoordenadaGPS, count(1) AS TOTAL_POINTS,
                (SELECT TOP 1 CONCAT(Latitud,' ', Longitud) FROM puntoGPS WHERE Id_CoordenadaGPS = x.Id_CoordenadaGPS AND Orden = 1) as first_point,
                (SELECT TOP 1 CONCAT(Latitud,' ', Longitud) FROM puntoGPS WHERE Id_CoordenadaGPS = x.Id_CoordenadaGPS AND Orden = (SELECT TOP 1 Orden 
                FROM puntoGPS WHERE Id_CoordenadaGPS = x.Id_CoordenadaGPS ORDER BY Orden DESC  )) as last_point
            FROM (
                SELECT TOP 1000000 latitud, longitud, id_CoordenadaGPS, Orden FROM puntoGPS
                WHERE Id_CoordenadaGPS IN (
                SELECT Id FROM CoordenadaGPS
                )
                ORDER BY orden
            ) x
            GROUP BY Id_CoordenadaGPS
        ) y
    ) z
) FIN
```

[PuntosGPS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tidbB.jpg)
Table with vertex coordinates, draw order and ID of the entity with corresponds.

[CoordenadasGPS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIcpc.png)
Table with ID , type of geometry and Name of each entity.

I need to create a ogr_geometry column in this table with the vertex information contained in PuntoGPS table.

If anyone has a "good way" to do all in one query would be awesome!

Thanks to all

Comment: How did you try to do it, and what, specifically, went wrong?

Comment: How is that data ending up in the table? Is it being sanitised before being inserted? (It doesn't look like it).

Comment: Storing queries that need to be executed is not only scary it is an indication that the design is not well thought out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @Sql_text as varchar(1000)

Select  @Sql_text = Sql_text from your table where idcordonadaGPS = 222

exec(@Sql_text)
```

Comment: Congratulations! Your database has just been victim of SQL Injection.

Comment: Luis, i undersand your point, however, if this is an internal script or something with no user input (so no sanitizing), I wouldn't worry about that :-)